# Convert Django DateField to usable value for React Calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, date, format

I have read the documentation for the react-calendar: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar, I have read the documentation for django DateField, and I have read similar questions on stack overflow.

My problem is trying to get the format YYYY MM dd that is saved in Django DateField to a usable value for the React calendar. I am currently trying to change the format using `const value = (locale, date) => formatDate(date, 'YYYY MMM dd')` and then calling the variable value when rendering the calendar component `<Calendar  value = {value}/>` but I don't know where to put the date variable that I've saved.

I currently have the date stored as a variable `{club.next}` which is dynamic for each page.

Comment: are you using axios to get those date values?

Comment: Yes @Schelmuffsky

Comment: then, my solution would be, to change the value into JS Date inside the get-action before axios dispatches them. I'll write an example in the answer, to make this easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, if this is good practice, but it saves you the work to convert the values in every component, where the `Django DateField` is needed.
I would even say that you're taking advantage of `Redux` this way. But I'm not a pro.

in you're actions:

```
export const getDates = () => dispatch => {
    axios.
        get('/api/dates/')
        .then(res => {
            for (let _date of res.data) {
                
                _date.start = new Date(_date.start);
                _date.end = new Date(_date.end);

            }
            dispatch({
                type: GET_DATES,
                payload: res.data
            });
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this inside a  tag before you load your react script and react will have access to it.

```
var date = new Date("{{ djangoDate.isoformat }}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const djangoDate = '2021 05 13';

const newDate = new Date(djangoDate.replace(' ','-'))
console.log(newDate)
```

Comment: I'm trying to convert a variable and when I do ```const djangoDate = {club.date}``` there is an error.

Comment: Sorry does the djangoDate look like "'YYYY MMM dd"?

Comment: hmm it should work. Maybe you need to do {club.date.toString()} or something. It works when I provide the date as a string constant.